# Input Validation and UI Exceptions with MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, mvvm-light

I am using MVVM using GalaSoft light Framework(mvvmlight(wpf4)). I have problems Validating Data input from the user and Displaying MessageBox indicating empty/incorrect input from the user,I wanted to use `INotifyDataErrorInfo` and this [article](http://mark.mymonster.nl/2011/02/22/validating-our-viewmodel) , but don't support in wpf4.

```
private string _password;
    private string _userName;

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Username is required")]
    public string UserName
    {
        get { return _userName; }
        set
        {
            if (_userName != value)
            {
                //  ValidateProperty("UserName", value);
                _userName = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("UserName");

            }
        }
    }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password
    {
        get { return _password; }
        set
        {
            if (_password != value)
            {
                //  ValidateProperty("Password", value);
                _password = value;
                base.RaisePropertyChanged("Password");
            }
        }
    }
```

How to use `Messanger` for input validation in mvvm light ?(send a message from save button to the ViewModel to check the input values.)

Comment: hey it it working for you..?

Comment: No, don't show message in validation.

Answer (score 2):

Thought I would add how I have pulled off input validation (model validation not just input) with MVVM light and the [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) framework. It has worked out well for me and allows you to attached "IsValid" to your model so you can validate at any time.

I wrote a detailed blog post about it. [MVVM Light and Model Validation](http://toadcode.blogspot.com/2013/12/mvvm-light-and-model-validation.html)

While it is true MVVM light itself does not have anything I wanted to provide a possible approach for others trying to pull this off. I have tried approaches with INotifyDataErrorInfo and others that are out there and found them lacking a bit. Hope it helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

you can send message on button.click event like this..

```
Messenger.Default.Send<string>("showattraction", "attraction");
```

first string is message and other is token for varifying it..

and where you recive this message do this..in constructor..

```
Messenger.Default.Register<string>(this, "attraction", GetLineDetails);
```

do your work in GetLineDetails method..

```
 public void GetLineDetails(string Message)
    {           
        // work here
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, can i use DataAnnotations and ValidatesOnExceptions in this way?